# R Use Dplyr to create a column that contain 1 of 6 possible values based on the value of 5 other columns

Tags: r, dplyr

in R, I am trying to create one column called model where the value depends on the value of up to 5 other columns.

The columns are Sport, Car, SUV, Wagon, Minivan, Pickup. These 5 columns have a value of 1 if it is a member of that group otherwise it has a 0. I would like to create one column called model that would equal 1 if Sport = 1,2 if SUV = 1, 3 if Wagon =1, 4 if Minivan = 1 , 5 if Pickup = 1 otherwise if all 5 columns equal 0 then model would = 0. I tried it using case statements and mutate using dplyr

```
cars %>%
mutate(model == case_when(Sport == 1, ~ '1' 
                ,case_when(SUV == 1, ~ '2' 
                ,case_when(Wagon == 1, ~'3' 
                  ,case_when(Minivan == 1, ~'4' 
                  ,case_when(Pickup == 1, ~ '5'
                  ,TRUE ~ 0))))))
```

but I got this error:

```
>     error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
   i `..1 = ==...`.
  x Case 1 (`Pickup == 1`) must be a two-sided formula, not a logical vector.
```

I have included a link to the file below.
[04cars.csv file]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't nest `case_when` statements, You just pass all your expressions to one call to `case_when`

```
cars %>%
  mutate(model = case_when(
    Sport == 1 ~ '1',
    SUV == 1 ~ '2',
    Wagon == 1 ~'3',
    Minivan == 1 ~'4',
    Pickup == 1 ~ '5',
    TRUE ~ 0))
```

One the first matching condition for each value will be used.

Comment: I added that code and I got the following error

Comment: You had extra commas in there as well. I’ve updated the answer to remove them.

Comment: So I have the following code:

Comment: So I have the following code:                                                                                        cars %>%
  mutate(model = case_when(
    Sport == 1 ~ '1',
    SUV == 1 ~ '2',
    Wagon == 1 ~'3',
    Minivan == 1 ~'4',
    Pickup == 1 ~ '5',
    TRUE ~ 0))                                                                                                                         and I get the error  'Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = ==...`.
x object 'model' not found'

Comment: I have also tried it the way it it written above and get the error: 'Error: unexpected numeric constant in:
"    Pickup == 1, ~ "5"
     TRUE"' not sure where my mistake is.

Comment: ok I figured out the error from above and it runs without error but no model variable is created. Here is the code:                                                                                                 cars %>%mutate(cars,model = case_when(Sport == 1 ~ '1',SUV == 1 ~ '2', Wagon == 1 ~'3',Minivan == 1 ~ '4',Pickup == 1 ~'5',TRUE ~ '0'))

Comment: figured it out. Thanks for your help.